# Advise on coding telephone number generating app phone number starts with 0

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

Hello am wondering if anyone could help me here, am new to programming and trying to write a program that generates telephone numbers starting from 0 the network provider starts with 0803 a total of 11 numbers. I want to generate some numbers for marketing. The error am getting says, invalid octal digit but i want it to work so I won't need to add zeros myself

```
1.  #include iostream
2.  #include fstream
3.  using namespace std;
4.  int main()
5.  {
6.  long numb = 08030000000;
7.  ofstream generated_numb;
8.  for(int i = 08030000000; i < 08040000000; i++)
9.  {
10. generated_numb.open("mtn_numbers.txt");
11. generated_numb << i << endl;
12. generated_numb.close();
13. }
14. while(true){}
15. return 0;
16. }
```

Comment: still looking for the reasons why I was blocked from asking questions, in just two questions. I have read the faqs still nothing related to why I was stopped from being able to post more messages/questions

Answer (score 2):

It would be best if you handled phone numbers as strings, for a variety of reasons.

The error you encountered is that several computer languages indicate octal (base 8) constants with a leading `0`.  To write a decimal number, start with a digit 1 through 9.

Phone numbers often contain various punctuation, like `.` `,` `-` `(` and `)` for starters.  Certain phone company internal numbers contain the "digits" `A` through `D`.  Also, extension numbers within a PBX are often separated by an `x`.

(response to first comment)

Something like this will accomplish your intent, since your requirement is non-general phone number processing:

```
FILE *f = fopen ("mtn_numbers.txt", "w");
if (!f)
    fprintf (stderr, "error opening output file\n");
else
{
    for (long n = 0;  n < 10000000;  ++n)
        fprintf (f, "0803%07Ld\n", n);
    fclose (f);
}
```

Comment: It is straightforward `C`, which works just fine in `C++`.  The string prefix `0803` followed by the format conversion `%07Ld` is medium-advanced, but it is what the doctor ordered.

Comment: Actually, there are 18 digits: `0-9`, `A-F`, and `*#`. The last two alias either `AB` or `EF` but that depends on your local phone system. (Obscure phone trivia part 98 ;))